# How to save remaning data of array in core data in Objective C

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, core-data

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to save the remaning data of array in Core data.
As shown in Image

[image]

I have select One button from table view and it save value in core data

For that my code is like this

```
 NSString *FailString=@"";
    NSString *WarningString=@"";

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSError *error;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AuditPost" inManagedObjectContext:context]];

    //  NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Result =%@",results);

    int imageSize   = imgData.length;
    NSLog(@"size of image in KB: %d ", imageSize/1024);
    int OCS=imageSize/1024;

    NSLog(@"OCS Image Size =%d",OCS);

    if(OCS<2)
    {
        AuditImageString=@"";
    }

    ComplareArray=[devices valueForKey:@"checkpointid"];

    BOOL contains = [ComplareArray containsObject:String2];

    if(contains == NO)
    {
        if (self.device) {
            // Update existing device
            [device setValue:Audit forKey:@"auditnameId"];
            [device setValue:String forKey:@"checklistid"];
            [device setValue:String2 forKey:@"checkpointid"];
            [device setValue:FailString forKey:@"failreason"];
            [device setValue:WarningString forKey:@"warningreason"];
            [device setValue:AuditStartDate forKey:@"starttimedate"];
            [device setValue:userid forKey:@"userid"];
            [device setValue:AuditImageString forKey:@"auditimage"];

            NSError *error = nil;
            // Save the object to persistent store
            if (![context save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            }

        } else {
            // Create a new device
            NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AuditPost" inManagedObjectContext:context];
            [newDevice setValue:Audit forKey:@"auditnameId"];
            [newDevice setValue:String forKey:@"checklistid"];
            [newDevice setValue:String2 forKey:@"checkpointid"];
            [newDevice setValue:FailString forKey:@"failreason"];
            [newDevice setValue:WarningString forKey:@"warningreason"];
            [newDevice setValue:AuditStartDate forKey:@"starttimedate"];
            [newDevice setValue:userid forKey:@"userid"];
            [newDevice setValue:AuditImageString forKey:@"auditimage"];

            NSError *error = nil;
            // Save the object to persistent store
            if (![context save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        // Save the object to persistent store
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AuditPost" inManagedObjectContext:context]];

        NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        NSManagedObject* favoritsGrabbed = [results objectAtIndex:CurrentIndexPath];
        [favoritsGrabbed setValue:String forKey:@"checklistid"];
        // Save the object to persistent store
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }

    //example reload table
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [Audittable reloadData];
    });
```

To save whole array in core data I am using code like this

```
if (self.device)
            {
                // Update existing device
                [device setValue:Audit forKey:@"auditnameId"];
                [device setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Passarray[i]] forKey:@"checklistid"];
                [device setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",CheckpointNameIDArray[i]] forKey:@"checkpointid"];
                [device setValue:FailString forKey:@"failreason"];
                [device setValue:WarningString forKey:@"warningreason"];
                [device setValue:AuditStartDate forKey:@"starttimedate"];
                [device setValue:userid forKey:@"userid"];
                [device setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",AuditImageString] forKey:@"auditimage"];
                NSError *error = nil;
                // Save the object to persistent store
                if (![context save:&error]) {
                    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Create a new device
                NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AuditPost" inManagedObjectContext:context];
                [newDevice setValue:Audit forKey:@"auditnameId"];
                [newDevice setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Passarray[i]] forKey:@"checklistid"];
                [newDevice setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",CheckpointNameIDArray[i]] forKey:@"checkpointid"];
                [newDevice setValue:FailString forKey:@"failreason"];
                [newDevice setValue:WarningString forKey:@"warningreason"];
                [newDevice setValue:AuditStartDate forKey:@"starttimedate"];
                [newDevice setValue:userid forKey:@"userid"];
                [newDevice setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",AuditImageString] forKey:@"auditimage"];

                NSError *error = nil;
                // Save the object to persistent store
                if (![context save:&error]) {
                    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
                }
             }
            }
            for (int i=0; i<PassarrIndexPaths.count; i++)
            {
                AuditNextTableViewCell *cell = [Audittable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[PassarrIndexPaths objectAtIndex:i]];
                DataModel *model = [arrData objectAtIndex:i];
                model.strSelected = @"P";
                [cell.passbtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
                [cell.failbtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
                [cell.wipbtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
                [cell.nabtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
            }
//            Passbtn.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
//            NAbtn.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
            [Audittable reloadData];
```

As in the Image
[image]
If I click on Mark Pending As PASS it save remaning array element in core data which is not select.For selection I am using code like this

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"AuditPost"];
            self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

            for (int i=0; i<PassarrIndexPaths.count; i++)
            {
                AuditNextTableViewCell *cell = [Audittable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[PassarrIndexPaths objectAtIndex:i]];
                DataModel *model = [arrData objectAtIndex:i];

                if([model.strSelected isEqualToString:@"P"])
                {

                }
                else if ([model.strSelected isEqualToString:@"W"])
                {

                }
                else if ([model.strSelected isEqualToString:@"F"])
                {

                }
                else if ([model.strSelected isEqualToString:@"NA"])
                {

                }
                else if ([model.strSelected isEqualToString:@"NAA"])
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    model.strSelected = @"PA";
                    [cell.passbtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
                    [cell.failbtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
                    [cell.wipbtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
                    [cell.nabtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
                }
```

I am facing problem is that if I save some data in core data then.How to save remaning data of array in core data.Did anybody done like this.Thanks in Adnavce!

Comment: What do you mean remaining data?

Comment: Create manage object model and save manage object context.

Comment: @Mukesh As in the Image I have saved one string from array in core data.On the click of Select all As Pass I need to save remaning data of array means skip first index and save the other value of array in core data.Is it is possible?

Comment: @Jitendra How to do that?

Comment: @Muju refer this link https://www.appcoda.com/core-data-tutorial-update-delete/

Comment: As per my understanding , if i am correct you have to fetch same record  which is saved previously take it in `Mutable` object & replace current status with prev. one only where you have to modify & save again.

Comment: @Mukesh No need to modify old data. Fetch data and insert data. By comparing count of array.

Comment: Honestly your question is not clearly visible to understand.

Comment: @Mukesh I need to compare data base array and Webservice array and then save data from web service array to core data.

Comment: You mean you want to save only new object & don't want to save already existed object right?

Comment: @Mukesh Yes right.

Answer (score 0):

If i am correct that you want to save data object which object is not already exist in the database Do simply,

```
-(void)save_UpdateData:(NSArray *)yourArray {

    NSManagedObjectContext *_context = [self getManagedObjectContext];

     for(int i = 0; i < [yourArray count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *details = [yourArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray *_arrayMappingObjects = [self getSavedDataFromDB];
        //Lets check mapping object exist in current record or not.
        //If not exist then create new one and add the same
        //If already exist, No need to add.
        NSPredicate *_predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"yourKey_predicate_id=%@",[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[details objectForKey:@"yourKey_predicate_id"] intValue]]];
        _arrayMappingObjects = [_arrayMappingObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:_predicate];
        if([_arrayMappingObjects count] > 0) {

          //Object already exist, No need to add the same object.

        } else {
            // Lets create an object add newly created instance
            ModelClass *modelObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ModelClass" inManagedObjectContext:_context];
            [modelObject setEntityName1:[details objectForKey:@"key1"]];//If your property is NSString
            [modelObject setEntityName2:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[details objectForKey:@"key2"] intValue]]];//If your property is NSNumber
            [modelObject setEntityName3:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[details objectForKey:@"key3"] intValue]]];

            [self saveContext];
        }
    }
}
```

//Get saved data

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getSavedDataFromDB {

    NSMutableArray *_record = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    NSManagedObjectContext *_context =[self getManagedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *_fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSEntityDescription *_entityDesc =[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ModelClass" inManagedObjectContext:_context];
    [_fetchRequest setEntity:_entityDesc];

    NSError *_error;
    NSArray *_fetchedOjects = [_context executeFetchRequest:_fetchRequest error:&_error];

    for(int i=0;i<[_fetchedOjects count];i++) {
        ModelClass *modelObject = [_fetchedOjects objectAtIndex:i];
        [_record addObject:modelObject];
    }
    return _record;
}
```

Comment: Consider this as a generic solution. You can change your code & logic as per your dependancy.